# How to Child Window Owner set in Winui3?

Tags: uwp, winui-3

I am Intermediate in winui.
I Just try to improve the skill.
I can not set Owner in child window .

I try to Owner set . but Winui Owner Property is not there.
Possible to set the Owner in Child Window.
Please give me solution.
Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Is it WinUI3 or UWP? they are not the same. WinUI3 can create other Windows (with an underlying HWND), so you can use the Windows API on these HWND (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/retrieve-hwnd), but there's nothing builtin.

Comment: There is a [AppWindow.Create(AppWindowPresenter, WindowId)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.create) Method to *Create a window with styles and properties as defined in the specified AppWindowPresenter and parented to the specified window*. For Certain pickers, popups, dialogs, and other Windows Runtime (WinRT) objects that depend on a CoreWindow, see [Display WinRT UI objects that depend on CoreWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/display-ui-objects).